# OOPHP select from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am wondering how to do the following I want to create a public function that allows me to do selects from MYSQL

Here is the code I have so far but it brings up a if error.

```
public function select($table,$options,$where,$orderby)
    {

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT ". 
        if($options)
        {
        $options
        }
        ." FROM ".
        $table
        if($where)
        {
        ." WHERE ".$where.
        }
        if ($orderby)
        {
        ." ORDER BY ".$orderby.
        }
        ."") or mysql_error() ;

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $rows[] = $row;
        print json_encode($rows);

    }
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/realcas/public_html/eshop/ecms/system/classes/database.php on line 23

Comment: I have written similar stuff for add and mod queries in mysql...let me know if you need it

Comment: That would be great, what is the best way to contact you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enhanced way:

```
public function select($table,$options,$where,$orderby)
{
    $options = empty($options) ? "*"   : $options;
    $where  =  empty($where)   ? "1=1" : $where;
    $orderby = empty($orderby) ? ""    : $orderby;

    $qry = "SELECT $options FROM $table WHERE $where $orderby ";
    $result= mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());

    while(($resultArray[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
    return json_encode($resultArray);

}
```

Comment: the downside with this, is that we need to show an error message back to the user if there is an error and also has to be in JSON formate

Comment: if you want to show the error messgage then do this  after while `return empty($resultArray) ? "Error in Query " ? json_encode($resultArray);`

Comment: Sorry I added that to the end of the code, and it did not work just gave me an error

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have if-statements inside a function call. Build your SQL outside and then pass it directly to mysql_query. Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT ";
if($options)
    $sql .= "FROM " . $table;
if($where)
    $sql .= " WHERE " . $where;
if($orderby)
    $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $orderby;

$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

I also assume that you're missing an `exit` before mysql_error(). As it is now, you wont get any output. Change it to:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Third, you will only be able to fetch a single row since you only invoke `mysql_fetch_assoc` once. You should continue iterating over it as long as there are results:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    $rows[] = $row;

// $rows will now contain all rows returned from your select statement
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT ". $options ." FROM ". $table .
                   ($where ? "WHERE " . $where : "") .
                   ($orderby? "ORDER BY ".$orderby  : "")) or mysql_error() ; 

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); 
$rows[] = $row; 
print json_encode($rows);
```